# How should we proceed with the [substrate-node] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

As most of us know the [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node) tag has been finding its way into many posts; often it is auto-suggested. This tag is redundant. It is like placing a [programming](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag on a Stack Overflow question.

This is a follow-up post after having discussions in chat with @JNat.

We came up with a remedy for this issue that we would like to present to the community:

- Create a [node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) synonym tag for [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node) tag and merge the two tags, resulting in only the [node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) tag being allowed to be used.

As commented by @JNat:

> Creating a synonym for a tag prevents the "source" tag from being used, and any time a user tries to use it the system will automatically remap it to the "target" tag — for that to work retroactively, we'd need to merge the tags

@JNat also asked if perhaps the questions that have [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node) tag made more sense with "related" synonyms such as [archive-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive-node), [full-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-node), [rpc-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpc-node), etc. If this was the case then our approach at solving this issue would be different. However, after reviewing the 261+ questions with the [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node) tag, I do not think this is the case - none of these questions had the context of a related tag.

If we can get confirmation that creating one synonym: [node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) and not multiple related synonyms is the way to solve this issue, then we will go ahead, create the [node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) synonym and merge the tag [node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node) with [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node).

Comment: Is it possible to fully remove the tag? And stop it auto suggesting.

Comment: For reference, moderators can use the tag merge tool to rename a tag without having to previously create the new name of the tag; just click "Merge" on the original tag's page, then type the new name for the tag, optionally choose whether you want to have the original tag name remain as a synonym of the new tag, and complete the "merge". (If that is, of course, what you decide to do.)

Comment: @DanShields: If you do end up renaming the tag in this way, there's a checkbox to choose whether or not the original tag name should remain as a synonym of the new tag. If the original tag name is causing problems (e.g. misuse of the tag on irrelevant questions), then not having it remain as a synonym may be the better solution; if you do keep `substrate-node` around as a synonym of `node`, then anyone who types `substrate` into the Tags field will see the [node] tag as a suggested tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed all 376+ uses of the [substrate-node] tag. According to the documentation, if a tag is not used in 24 hours the tag is automatically deleted.

It has been over 24 hours, the [substrate-node] tag [no longer exists](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name).

Hopefully this resolves the issue.